# psycopg2 OperationalError: invalid connection option

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg

I am using [records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records/blob/master/records.py) library to connect to redshift database. My db_url is something like

```
postgresql://xxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/customer?user=xxxxx&password=xxxxx
```

I am using this piece of code to connect to db. On my local machine it works perfectly fine.

```
import records
>>> conn_url = 'postgresql://xxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/customer?user=xxxxx&password=xxxxx'
>>> db = records.Database(conn_url)
```

but on the server machine its giving me this error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/extractor/virtualenv/hge/lib/python2.7/site-packages/records.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.db = psycopg2.connect(self.db_url, cursor_factory=RecordsCursor)
  File "/opt/extractor/virtualenv/hge/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

psycopg2.OperationalError: invalid connection option "postgresql://xxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/customer?user"
```

Both the machines have same version of library installed

```
psycopg2==2.6.1
records==0.3.0
```

The only thing that differ is the OS. My local has Mac OX whereas the server is on `CentOS 6.7`

I am not able to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded my records library to `records==0.4.3` and it worked